# Javascript Not Sorting Prices Correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, sorting

I'm sorting a list of prices with this code:

```
var $divs = $("div.machinebox");
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return $(a).find("p.price").text() < $(b).find("p.price").text() ? 1 : -1;
});
$("#machinewrapper").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
```

I want to sort the list of prices from highest to lowest, so they look like this:

```
$549.00  
$387.00  
$248.99  
$242.91  
$97.01  
$32.04
```

The problem is it's sorting them like this:

```
$97.01  
$549.00  
$387.00  
$32.04  
$248.99  
$242.91
```

Any ideas how to get this to sort properly?  Thanks!

Comment: You're sorting strings, alphabetically. Just google `money string to number js` or whatever and sort by that

Comment: I did just as you said and found the answer.  I didn't realize what the problem was to know what to Google, so thanks.

Comment: @Tmac If an answer is found then mark it as accepted. If you came up with your own, then create a new answer explaining what you did and mark that as the correct one.

Answer (score 1):

For a quick fix I recommend storing an unformatted value in an attribute on the element. The problem is that it's sorting by characters, not numerically.

Try something like this instead:

```
var $divs = $("div.machinebox");
var numericallyOrderedDivs = $divs.sort(function (a, b) {
            return parseFloat($(a).attr('data-sort')) < parseFloat($(b).attr('data-sort')) ? 1 : -1;
});
$("#machinewrapper").html(numericallyOrderedDivs);
```

In this case, whenever you have a `.price` item, you set the `data-sort` value to the parent `div` (to optimize the sort a bit). Then you can just parse float on that value to compare the strings.

Example HTML:

```
<div class="machinebox" data-sort="1367.42" >
  <a class="price">$1,367.42</a>
</div>
```

**For a better solution:** I highly recommend you use some MV* framework/library to better handle the union of logic and UI. It's better practice to sort your models then render/update your views. Most popular are [Backbone.js](http://backbonejs.org/), [Angular.js](https://angularjs.org/), [Ember.js](http://emberjs.com/). (Backbone is great for starting out, very easy to implement and helps teach some great practices.)